# Creating a simple shell to perform input and output redirection command line operators

Tags: c, linux, shell, exec, file-descriptor

I have to write a shell that for example execute commands like 
`$ ls -l > directory.txt` or `$ grep "some phrase" < somefile.txt`
 I have successfully parsed the command given by the user as below:

> cmd = "ls"
>
> arg[0] = "ls"
>
> arg[1] = "-l"
>
> outfile = "directory.txt"

I can execute 
`$ ls -l` using vfork() and execlp(). How do proceed further?

Comment: Be cautious about using `vfork()`; the constraints on when it can be used are very stringent.  A general purpose shell won't use `execlp()` — it will use `execvp()` because you can't predict how many arguments will be needed at compile time.  There are thousands of questions in the C tag about writing custom shells.  You can find answers in those.

Comment: Thank you, I switched it to execvp()